# HTML markup rendering issue in ViewData? Also, MultiView functionality in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, viewdata

i'm trying to populate a ViewData instance with html markup like shown below. When the page renders, the html tags get rendered as text and not html markup. Anyone know why?

Controller code:

```
if (user.ActivationStatus == false)
{
    ...
    ViewData["Message"] = "<p>Your account has been activated, you're good to go.</p>";
}
    else 
{
    ViewData["Message"] = "<p>Sorry, this account has already been activated.</p>";
}
return View();
```

View code:

```
<h2>Confirmation</h2>
<p><%: ViewData["Message"] %></p>
```

Secondly, I have used the MultiView feature in asp.net webforms in the past. This functionality is ideal and like to implement a similar functionality in MVC.

Is there any way i can call different PartialViews dependant on the function outcome(like the 'if' statement above) from controller code to a placeholder in the View?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<%: %>` == `Html.Encode(ViewData["Message"]);`is HTML Encoding your string...

Try this:

```
<%= ViewData["Message"]%>
```

Also, you should be able to control Partial Controls using `ViewData` and depending on the values in `ViewData` you could render different partials. You could also strongly type your view to a model that represents the behavior your after on the page...

Answer (score 4):

You can create an [MvcHtmlString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461471.aspx)

```
<%: MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewData["Message"]) %>
```

But really you should not have the html in your controller.
By making your view strongly-typed you could instead do something like this.

```
<h2>Confirmation</h2>
<% if(Model.ActivationStatus) { %>
  <p>Sorry, this account has already been activated.</p>
<% } else { %>
  <p>Your account has been activated, you're good to go.</p>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your view output to:

```
<h2>Confirmation</h2>
<p><%= ViewData["Message"] %></p>
```

Only use `<%: %>`  syntax when you want output to be automatically HTML encoded.